# 403 Forbidden in Xcode Simulator but works fine with Xcode Canvas Preview

Tags: django, xcode, swiftui

I'm wrote a Login page with SwiftUI, and a backend with Django(both running in my laptop)

the login api works fine no matter using Postman or in Xcode Canvas Preview

but when I run the Xcode Project with Simulator, the Login func would fail

the backend returns 403 forbidden

Funny thing is, it works fine until yesterday, and I didn't change the code, just suddenly it won't work in the simulator

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

I tried to disable the `csrf middleware` in Django `setting.py`, and it didn't work

---

here's my SwiftUI code:

```swift
func sendOTP(phoneNumber: String) -> Bool{
    if phoneNumber.count != 11 {
        return false
    }
    guard let url=URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/") else {
        return false
//        fatalError("Missing URL")
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    // Most likely you want to add some token here
    // request.setValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    // request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    let requestData = [
        "request_type": "sms_auth",
        "phone_number": phoneNumber,
    ]
    
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encodedData = try? encoder.encode(requestData) {
        urlRequest.httpBody = encodedData
    } else {
        return false
    }
    
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Request error: ", error)
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {return}
        
        if response.statusCode == 200 {
            guard let data = data else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(KCWebRes<String>.self, from: data)
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error decoding: ", error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
    
    return true
}
```

and here's my Django code:

```py
class Login(APIView):
    def post(self, request):

        if not "phont_number" not in request.data:
            pass

        phone_number = request.data["phone_number"]
        if not KCUser.phone_number_auth(phone_number):
            ret = login_sc.fail
            return JsonResponse(ret)

        con_redis = get_redis_connection(alias='verify_codes')

        request_type = request.data["request_type"]
        if request_type == "sms_auth":
            sms_code = "%06d" % random.randint(0, 999999)
            if con_redis.exists("sms_send_" + phone_number):
                ret = login_sc.sms_fail
                return JsonResponse(ret)

            rds_pl = con_redis.pipeline()
            try:
                rds_pl.setex("sms_send_" + phone_number, 60, 1)  
                rds_pl.setex("sms_code_" + phone_number, 300, sms_code)
                rds_pl.execute()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            sms_auth(phone_number, sms_code)
            ret = login_sc.sms_sent
            return JsonResponse(ret)

        elif request_type == "login":
            request_sms_code = request.data["sms_code"]
            _code = con_redis.get("sms_code_" + phone_number).decode()
            if not request_sms_code or not _code:
                ret = login_sc.sms_code_error
                return JsonResponse(ret)

            if request_sms_code != _code:
                ret = login_sc.sms_code_error
                return JsonResponse(ret)
            else:
                if KCUser.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).count() == 0:
                    user = KCUser.objects.create_user(
                        phone_number=phone_number,
                        username=phone_number,
                        password="qazwsxedc"  # TODO password
                    )
                    user.save()
                else:
                    user = KCUser.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)

                login(request, user)
                ret = login_sc.success
                ret["data"] = KCUserSerializer(user).data
                return JsonResponse(ret)

        state = login_sc.fail
        return JsonResponse(state)
```

Comment: Without some code it's almost impossible to suggest anything. Also, since it's your own backend, I'd suggest looking into the logs and figure out what's the difference between the requests.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Thanks for your advice! I've added my code, it's quite simple though, I sent a request from swift and get some response from the backend.

Comment: Note, Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" in your `Info.plist` to allow http connection to the server. Have you done that?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks, I have it set, but it still won't work

Comment: Using 127.0.01 may not be a good choice as it’s supposed to be localhost which may be the simulator not the Mac. Try to use the Mac IP address

Answer (score 0):

everyone, I found out what's going on there.
It's because the lack of csrf-token in the request. But I still don't understand why disable `csrf-middleware` in django `setting.py` doesn't work.